# Change border color of textbox when it is clicked inside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have this `span` containing an input:

```html
 <span class="min-max">
        <input class="min-max-input" type="number" 
               ng-blur="$ctrl.blur('text')" ng-change="$ctrl.changeText('text')"
               ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}" ng-model="$ctrl.text">
    </span>
```

Now, when I'm clicking inside nothing changes on visual part. What I would like is to have a highlight or something like changing the border color of the textbox into light blue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well you can already give `ng-click` a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS style rule:

```
.min-max-input:focus {
  outline: 3px ridge cyan
}
```

What makes [**`outline`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) different from [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) is that `border` lengths are counted in measurements while `outline` isn't. Besides the fact that you don't need to remember to include it in measuring dimensions, there isn't a shift when it appears and disappears. The pseudo-class [**`:focus`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) works like the [`focus` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) to a lesser degree.

#### Demo

```css
input {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px auto
}

/* box-shadow optional */

.min-max-input:focus {
  outline: 3px ridge cyan;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 4px rgba(0, 187, 150, 0.5);
}

.min-max-input.sangre:focus {
  outline: 3px ridge tomato;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 4px rgba(235, 66, 48, 0.5);
}

.min-max-input.verdant:focus {
  outline: 3px ridge lime;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 4px rgba(111, 255, 111, 0.5);
}

.min-max-input.flaxen:focus {
  outline: 3px ridge gold;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 4px rgba(220, 230, 70, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<span class="min-max">
    <input class="min-max-input" type="number" 
           ng-blur="$ctrl.blur('text')" ng-change="$ctrl.changeText('text')"
           ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}" ng-model="$ctrl.text">
</span>

<span class="min-max">
    <input class="min-max-input sangre" type="number" 
           ng-blur="$ctrl.blur('text')" ng-change="$ctrl.changeText('text')"
           ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}" ng-model="$ctrl.text">
</span>

<span class="min-max">
    <input class="min-max-input verdant" type="number" 
           ng-blur="$ctrl.blur('text')" ng-change="$ctrl.changeText('text')"
           ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}" ng-model="$ctrl.text">
</span>

<span class="min-max">
    <input class="min-max-input flaxen" type="number" 
           ng-blur="$ctrl.blur('text')" ng-change="$ctrl.changeText('text')"
           ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}" ng-model="$ctrl.text">
</span>
```

Comment: _I liked tomato more_

Comment: Me to, I updated answer with 3 more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the CSS `:focus` pseudo-class:

```
input.min-max-input:focus {
   border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
```

Added benefit of this pseudo-class is that when the element loses focus, the light blue border will disappear, which makes it more a11y-compliant.